# Counting number of strings within strings in lists

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have the following two lists which includes only string objects.

```
list1 = ['UC1', 'UC1,UC2', 'UC3' ]
list2 = ['UC1', 'UC2', 'UC3']
```

I want to check how many time `UC1`, `UC2`, `UC2` appear in `list1`

The expected result should be 2,1, and 1 respectively.

In practice I have millions of objects in `list1` and `list2` respectively

Can someone help me do to that in python as efficiently as possible ?

Thanks

Comment: `list2.count('UC1')`?

Comment: The problem is that I have millions of objects in `list2' that should check ... is there some better way ?

Comment: Is your `list1` correctly defined, i.e has 3 elemenets? or a typo in there?

Comment: No, it has millions of elements -- in the example, is indeed three.

Comment: what about numpy.count() ?

Answer (score 1):

```
n = [len([j for j in list1 if i in j]) for i in list2]
```

output

> [2, 1, 1]

Answer (score 0):

This is complex.
For the count of any element in a list, we must traverse the all list. So time complexity is equal to O(n). For this step, there is not much we can do. I recommend the `sklearn.feature_extract.text.TFIDFTransform`.

For knowing the count of all `element`, we should store the count and quick get out the count. I recommend the dictionary or `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.